# ksh - var = $var + 1 returns 1+1 string

Tags: string, shell, integer, increment, ksh

My code:

```
RETVAL1=-1
if [ $RETVAL1 -le 0 ] ; then
  RETVAL1=$RETVAL1+1
  print "RETVAL1: $RETVAL1"
fi
```

And it prints `RETVAL1: -1+1`
Any idea how to repair it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform arithmetic operation, use the `let` command: `let RETVAL1=RETVAL1+1`

Moreover, enclosing the expression between `$((` and `))` would also interpret it as an arithmetic operation.  `echo $((RETVAL+1))`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`let`](http://ss64.com/bash/let.html) command. This command performs arithmic operations. The `+` operator performs string addition.

Use it like this:

```
let RETVAL1=RETVAL1+1
```

You can also use the [expr](http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html) command for more general expressions.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! I think I should learn ksh bit more then. (mostly for not to look like an idiot when asking question like this after an hour trying)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
((RETVAL1=RETVAL1+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell variables don't work like variables in most programming languages. If you want to add 1 to an integer stored in a variable, you'll need an arithmetic expression. I'm no `ksh` wizard, but the usual Bourne-derived-shell arithmetic expression syntax is:

```
RETVAL1=$((RETVAL1 + 1))
```

or

```
((RETVAL1 = RETVAL1 + 1))
```